Apache Superset (v 4.0.2) not showing options when i use "IN" operator in a filter
While adding a filter to a chart I'm creating, I expect to see a dropdown menu with all the options from the column I choose when I select the 'IN' operator. However, in my case, the dropdown is blank, so I have to type all the values manually, which is time-consuming and prone to errors. Is anyone else experiencing the same problem?
